# How to deduce the return type of a std::bind object for template use?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-deduction

I have a class which basically just manages a vector of custom types. To relieve me from writing the same iteration loop over and over again I wrote the following construct:

```
template<typename T>
uint64_t ACCUMULATE_ON_VECTOR(const std::vector<MyClass*> vec, T method)
{
  return std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0, [&](uint64_t acc, const MyClass* c)
  {
    return acc + (c ? method(c) : 0);
  });
}
```

which is then called like this:

```
ACCUMULATE_ON_VECTOR(_myVec, std::bind(&MyClass::someMethod, std::placeholders::_1));
```

This works very well in concept but since I have a lot of methods returning different integer types (signed/unsigned, signed/unsigned long), I'd like to abstract away the for now hardcoded uint64_t cause I get compiler warnings all over the place. For this I somehow need to get the return type of the bind object. Can I somehow do this with decltype? What I'm looking for is this:

```
template<typename T>
<new deduced type> ACCUMULATE_ON_VECTOR(const std::vector<MyClass*> vec, T method)
{
  return std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0, [&](<new deduced type> acc, const MyClass* c)
  {
    return acc + (c ? method(c) : 0);
  });
}
```

Comment: Does this need to work with c++11, or is c++14 ok? If so, you could use `auto`.

Comment: Would [`result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using [`std::result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of):

```
template<typename Func>
typename std::result_of<Func(MyClass*)>::type
ACCUMULATE_ON_VECTOR(const std::vector<MyClass*> &vec, Func method)
{
  using ResultType = typename std::result_of<Func(MyClass*)>::type;
  return std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), ResultType{},
                         [&](typename std::result_of<Func(MyClass*)>::type acc,
                             const MyClass* c)
  {
    return acc + (c ? method(c) : ResultType{});
  });
}
```

Note I'm value-initializing the return type instead of using the integer literal zero.

It might be more readable to wrap the function parameter in a `std::function<ResultT(MyClass*)>`: the accumulate function would be directly templated on the result type, pushing responsibility for that up to the call site.

---

BTW, you don't need the `auto`/trailing return type technique here, because the return type doesn't depend on the argument list, only on the template parameter - nevertheless, I think it looks slightly nicer:

```
template<typename Func>
auto ACCUMULATE_ON_VECTOR(const std::vector<MyClass*> &vec,
                          Func method)
-> typename std::result_of<Func(MyClass*)>::type
{
```

Answer (score 3):

[`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) has a member type called `result_type` which is

> 1) If F is a pointer to function or a pointer to member function, result_type is the return type of F. If F is a class type with nested typedef result_type, then result_type is F::result_type. Otherwise no result_type is defined.
>
> 2) result_type is exactly R.

We can use a trailing return type like

```
template<typename T>
auto ACCUMULATE_ON_VECTOR(const std::vector<MyClass*> vec, T method) -> typename T::result_type
{
  typename T::result_type begin = 0;
  return std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), begin, [&](typename T::result_type acc, const MyClass* c)
  {
    return acc + (c ? method(c) : 0);
  });
}
```

This will work with C++11 and above.

I also added `typename T::result_type begin = 0;` to the function so the type passed to accumulate is the same type as the return of the function.  As you just had `0` that gets deduced to an `int` and `accumulate` will always return an `int`.

Comment: That `result_type` is not very useful in generic code.

Comment: @T.C. I agree but I wanted to make the OP aware of it and how it could be used.  I actually voted for the accepted answer as I feel that does the best job.

Answer (score 0):

If using C++14 is ok you can just substitute your mystery type for `auto`.

If you're limited to C++11 you can use the following slightly uglier solution:

```
template<typename T>
auto ACCUMULATE_ON_VECTOR(const std::vector<MyClass*> vec, T method) -> 
    typename std::result_of<decltype(method)(MyClass*)>::type
{
  return std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0,
     [&](typename std::result_of<decltype(method)(MyClass*)>::type acc, const MyClass* c)
  {
    return acc + (c ? method(c) : 0);
  });
}
```

This gives you the type that the result of a call to `method` on a `MyClass*` would have.

---

By the way, there's really no need to use `bind` at the call site. You could achieve the same thing using a lambda:

```
ACCUMULATE_ON_VECTOR(_myVec, [] (const MyClass* p) { return p->someMethod(); });
```

(In C++14 you could replace `const MyClass*` with `auto` if you wanted to)

Answer (score 0):

The result type of accumulate has nothing to do with the passed accumulating function. **The result type of accumulate is the type of the third parameter.** You're getting warnings because your third parameter is `0` (which is int) so the `int64` will get truncated to `int` anyway! You should pass `int46(0)` as your third parameter for a warning-free code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits)

```
template<typename T>
auto ACCUMULATE_ON_VECTOR(const std::vector<MyClass*> vec, T method) 
    -> typename std::iterator_traits<T(MyClass*)>::value_type
{
    return std::accumulate(
        vec.begin(), 
        vec.end(), 
        0, 
        [&](typename std::iterator_traits<T(MyClass*)>::value_type acc, const MyClass* c)
        {
            return acc + (c ? method(c) : 0);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what `std::iterator_traits` is for